What if Hibernate Query.list() is called again?
I have some code like this (not made by me):
if (query.list() != null && !query.list().isEmpty())
    resultObj = (MyObject) query.list().get(0);

What happens when it calls query.list() three times that way?
Does it contact the database three times, or after the first time does it prevent calling the database again somehow?

If query is a Query-object, then the Hibernate docs state

Queries are executed by calling list(), scroll() or iterate(). A query may be re-executed by subsequent invocations. Its lifespan is, however, bounded by the lifespan of the Session that created it.

So I would indeed assume that the database is queried three times.
But what stops you from saving it in a variable before the if? It would also be a lot cleaner.

Infact, I'm asking that to understand if it's better to modify the code to save it into a variable before the if checks, and then use the variable.
Seeing that it's a code from a bigger project, with a bigger team than just me, my changes have to be justified.
